# Book about an abducted boy who uses electronics to communicate

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read it in 2019 but I'm not sure if it was a new or older book. It's a novel where a boy (probably less than 13) is kidnapped according to his mother and no one believes her. No one believed her because they all thought he had died in a school bus crash (I think). She then decides to look for him herself with the help of a guy who I think likes her, when she feels like her son was trying to communicate with her using appliances in their home to tell her where he is.
I remember this part where she tries to use hypnosis to clear her mind in order to hear her son better.
When trying to convince the guy, who's helping her, that her son was actually kidnapped because he was special, the two reasons she gave were:

1. That a dog they had had run away and didn't come back but the boy mourned the dog's death like he knew the dog had actually died and not just run off.
2. That the first time the boy (her son) played cards without ever being taught how to, he won outstandingly.